# How do you automatically match foreign key value to primary key value when creating a new record?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

First thing first, I am working with C# and MS Access 2013. Now that I got that out of the way, I am having trouble matching my foreign keys in the child table to the primary keys in the parent table.

I currently have a table "Customers" with the PK being CustomerID and Autonumber. I have another table named "Dogs" with the PK being DogID and Autonumber. Then I have a table named "Reservations" with fields CustomerID and DogID as foreign Keys and number.

In Visual Studios 2013 I have created forms that takes information from the user and sends the data to the database to their appropriate tables. For instance, when there is a new customer I take all the information I need for a new customer and insert it as a new record in the "Customer" table. Then this customer makes a reservation for their dog so I take the dog's information and send it as a new record to the "Dogs" table. At this point, the new records in the "Customers" and "Dogs" table have their primary keys set. I then have to make a reservation and insert a new record to the "Reservation" table. As I said, this table has fields CustomerID and DogID as foreign Keys and must match the primary key of the customer and dog that were just created.

How can I make this happen ? Does it have to be with a query ? Do i need to do it manually ? I am pretty new to databases and would appreciate the help. Thank You !

Comment: The database generates the AutoNumber values when you insert the records and then you must retrieve them. The best way to do that depends on EXACTLY how you're working with the data. If you're calling `ExecuteNonQuery` to insert records then a query to retrieve `@@IDENTITY` afterwards will get the last auto-generated value. Just be aware that if multiple users are connecting to the database then you may get interference.

Comment: I am using `ExecuteNonQuery` to insert records. How exactly do I create a query to retrieve `@@IDENTITY` ? I never created a query before not to mention using `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: A query is simply a `SELECT` statement. You should do some research on `SELECT` statements and on the `@@IDENTITY` variable in Access.  That's what you should always do when someone gives you keywords.  I doubt that you'll have much trouble finding examples of exactly what I've described.

Comment: Thanks so much. This has pointed me to the right direction

Comment: Getting the @@Identity value is hokey in Access.  Be sure to read the example here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815629/how-to-retrieve-the-identity-value-while-inserting-records-into-access-database-by-using-visual-basic-net and be sure to use the same Connection object that you used to add the record.